# Dajngo forms placeholder and mask: data correctly saved in database but wrongly displayed at screen

Tags: django, data-masking

I have an issue with formatting floatfield in Django.
I set placehodler and data-mask: 000.0

When I enter data infields, it is correctly save in database but when I display form, it is wrongly displayed.

For example, I enter '078.1' for weight. 78.1 is saved in database but when I open form, 781 is displayed. It seeems that 'missing' 0 at the beggining of floatnumber make it slice in the left and I lost comma

models.py

```
inc_poi = models.FloatField('Poids (kg)', null=True, blank=True)
```

forms.py

```
self.fields['inc_poi'] = forms.FloatField(label = 'Poids (kg)',widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'placeholder': '000.0','data-mask':'000.0'}),required=False,disabled=DISABLED)
```

Answer (score 0):

I found, data-mak should be 999.0 to allow up to 3 digit before decimal